# PHP 7.2.2 + mysql 8.0 PDO gives: authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm using php 7.2.2 and mysql 8.0.

When I try to connect with the right credential I get this error:

```
PDOException::("PDO::__construct(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]")
```

Need help to troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: MySQL 8.0 isn't production ready jet. PHP devs might have not implemented the MySQL's 8.0 connection protocol ( auth with caching_sha2_password ) within the newer PHP versions. You might be able to fix this problem if you configure MySQL 8.0 to run in mysql_native_password mode.

Comment: That's ok. It seems there is no option mysql_native_password=1 configurable into mycnf, also using it from mysql client is possible by command line, and seems also available in pdo as option. Just cannot figure out how to compose things together.

Comment: In MySQL 8, a new auth plugin was introduced: caching_sha2_password.  That plugin does NOT work with PHP because the PHP's mysqlnd has NOT been updated.  PHP 7.2.4 or higher will work with the OLD auth plugin (mysql_native_password) if you convert the mysql user account PHP connects to the db with to the old authentication!  ALTER USER 'user_name'@'hostname' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';  In your /etc/my.cnf file you can add: default_authentication_plugin = mysql_native_password But this default only works for all new accounts created going forward.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to use MySQL >= 8 and you don't care about `caching_sha2_password`, just select the second option when you install.

[image]

Comment: I would choose this answer if you provide instructions to obtain same result using bash on Linux.

Comment: After hours of attempting various things, this was the only thing that worked for me

Comment: METHOD WITHOUT UNISTALLING MYSQL: Just download MySql Installer only and then execute it. Follow the instructions, Select "reconfigure MySql Server" and change the autenthication method to "Use Legacy Auth Method". (you don't need to stop mysql service. easy and fast)

Answer (score 43):

```
alter user 'username'@'localhost' identified with mysql_native_password by 'password';
```

As suggested by `ailionx` here : https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/1390

Comment: This is what solved for me.

Comment: That is correct, I had to do a mix of that answer and edit of `[mysqld]
default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password` in `my.cnf` file as described here https://mysqlserverteam.com/upgrading-to-mysql-8-0-default-authentication-plugin-considerations/ and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50026939/php-mysqli-connect-authentication-method-unknown-to-the-client-caching-sha2-pa

Comment: I also did the same as @nyluje

Answer (score 31):

Found this somewhere, don't remember where (or I would credit), but it works for me until MySQL 8 gets better.

In MySQL shell (command prompt, whatever):

```
CREATE USER username@localhost identified with mysql_native_password by 'password';
```

Where *username* is the username and *password* is the password for that user.

Then you can add permissions in the shell - or in the Workbench as the user now exists with Authentication Type: Standard.

Comment: Thanks for this! I am tinkering with PHP 7.2.5 along with MySQL 8. Couldn't connect by creating a user through the workbench interface but running this query did the job for me.

Comment: Thanks for this, it worked for me on MySQL 8.0.13.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Just start your mysql with mysqld --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password --console

Comment: @Reid " And PHP is ready for MySQL's caching_sha2_password."  This sentence is wrong/misleading.  I advise you to remove that sentence from your answer.  In fact, you go on to create a new user using the mysql_native_password plugin, not the caching_sha2_password.  PHP does NOT work with the caching_sha2_password plugin, but it does work with the mysql_native_password plugin.  References:  https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html

Comment: not work for me

Comment: @TSGantiSOdarkforces Thanks for your comment.  Running `mysql.server start --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password --console` solved this for me.

Answer (score 8):

In order to use mySQL 8 (with the new authentication method) you could just upgrade your PHP.

> MySQL 8
>
> When running a PHP version before 7.1.16, or PHP 7.2 before 7.2.4, set MySQL 8  Server's default password plugin to mysql_native_password or else you will see errors similar to The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password] even when caching_sha2_password is not used.

reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php

Comment: MySQL 8's caching_sha2_password authentication plugin will not work at all with PHP as of yet. PHP 7.2.4 or higher will work with MySQL 8 if you convert the mysql user account PHP uses to the OLD authentication:  ALTER USER 'user_name'@'hostname' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';  Or you can create a new account referencing the Old authentication. The [mysqld] default_authentication_plugin = mysql_native_password directive only affects new accounts.  It doesn't affect existing user accounts.

Comment: @James any updates to the status of `caching_sha2_password` in PHP PDO?

Comment: @Meglio MySQL is still reporting: " PHP: the PDO_MySQL and ext/mysqli extensions do not support caching_sha2_password."   Follow this link  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html and search for PDO.

Comment: @Meglio Also, PHP documentation indicates PDO does not support the caching_sha2_password.   Reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php