# php mysqli_connect: authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]

Tags: php, mysql, hash, sha

I am using php `mysqli_connect` for login to a MySQL database (all on localhost)

```
<?php
//DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'user2');
//DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', 'pass2');
DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'user1');
DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', 'pass1');
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'dbname');

$dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

if(!$dbc){
    die('error connecting to database');    
}
?>
```

this is the mysql.user table:
[image: mysql.user table]

MySQL Server ini File:

```
[mysqld]
# The default authentication plugin to be used when connecting to the server
default_authentication_plugin=caching_sha2_password
#default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password
```

with `caching_sha2_password` in the MySQL Server ini file, it's not possible at all to login with user1 or user2;

> error: mysqli_connect(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password] in...

with `mysql_native_password` in the MySQL Server ini file, it's possible to login with user1, but with user2, same error;

---

how can I login using `caching_sha2_password` on the mySql Server?

Comment: Does PDO support this? I've seen other reports about `mysqli`.

Comment: Answer posted by @黃皓哲 should be marked as accepted answer.

Comment: From terminal login to mysql with this command : mysql -u root -p then enter root password,  then paste the following command ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'root';

Comment: For anyone who is having no luck from the below answers: I also got this error message in a Laravel app when I had the wrong IP for the database in my .env file!

Answer (score 100, accepted):

**As of PHP 7.4, this is no longer an issue. Support for `caching_sha2` authentication method has been added to mysqlnd.**

---

Currently, PHP mysqli extension do not support new caching_sha2 authentication feature.
You have to wait until they release an update.

Check related post from MySQL developers: https://mysqlserverteam.com/upgrading-to-mysql-8-0-default-authentication-plugin-considerations/

They didn't mention PDO, maybe you should try to connect with PDO.

Comment: PDO [has the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49083573/php-7-2-2-mysql-8-0-pdo-gives-authentication-method-unknown-to-the-client-ca)

Comment: @Machavity do you know if this answer is still valid? Ie. it's not outdated yet with newer PHP versions?

Comment: @gen Based on [this bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=78981), looks like it's working as of 7.4.2

Comment: Upgrading to php7.4 does solved the issue. And I think that is the best approach rather than changing the authentication method to `mysql_native_password` as suggested by some answers.

Comment: I use docker (apache+php in a container and mysql in other container) and this solved my Issue. Thanks!

Comment: PHP 7.4.3 here. Had to change to `mysql_native_password` for it to work.

Comment: I have `PHP 7.4.27 (cli) (built: Jan 20 2022)`, still I needed `mysql_native_password`!

Answer (score 333):

I solve this by SQL command:

```
ALTER USER 'mysqlUsername'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'mysqlUsernamePassword';
```

which is referenced by https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-user.html

if you are creating new user

```
 CREATE USER 'jeffrey'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

which is referenced by https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-user.html

this works for me

Comment: Good answer. The gotcha here is you might have to do this every time you add a new user, depending on the server settings

Comment: Thank you very much I was looking for a way to convert the new password hashes to the older ones (like user2 format to user1 format in the question) and your answer did exactly the job

Comment: And so ended a 4 day struggle to get the php-7.2.9/11 playing nice with MySQL-8.012.  Could someone on the PHP team be convinced to note this in the INSTALL in the tarball?  It would save thousands of person hours over the next year or two.

Comment: this should be accepted answer for workaround solution

Comment: ERROR 1819 (HY000): Your password does not satisfy the current policy requirements

Comment: This worked for me with php7.0 and mysql 8.0 on CentOS just make sure you also restart mysqld

Comment: Perfect! It work for me too! Just conected to database SYS and execute the Alter command above. Thanks!

Comment: Alter didn't work for me, so, I dropped and created the user instead. Thank you.

Comment: Switching to native authentication basically means you weakened the overall security to allow access. That gives you access but can't be considered a long-term, secure solution. And as @Dimmduh pointed out, you may end up with "ERROR 1819 (HY000): Your password does not satisfy the current policy requirements"

Comment: @cgclip YES: just make sure you also restart mysqld !!

Comment: This worked for me, as I choosed new authentication type, but my application does not support it. So I had to "downgrade" it and this solved it.

Comment: That should be the accepted answer but unfortunately nothing in life is fair ! Thank you

Comment: Thank you, it work for me. I use php 7.3 and mysql 8.0 on macOS catalina

Comment: I'm a little late, but for anyone who is trying to access a remote mysql server over a local IP, the ALTER USER line should also be run for your local internet IP instead of 'localhost'

Comment: Thx. This worked for me. But i want understand why this works (can sb expand this answer) - for me this problem was related with phpmyadmin on fresh mysql server 8.

Comment: After this restarting mysqld with `--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password` made it work for me.

Comment: this answer made me create a password and now I cant even connect, wrong answer.

Comment: Works! If you are using Laravel Valet and trying to get PHP 7.3 to work, use `mysql-exec "ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '';" && brew services restart mysql` to make this configuration change.

Comment: This advice should be included in your mandatory snippets.

Comment: If you run into MySQL's `ERROR 1396: Operation ALTER USER failed for 'mysqlUsername'@'localhost'`, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69039215/12824563)

Answer (score 45):

```
ALTER USER 'mysqlUsername'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'mysqlUsernamePassword';
```

Remove quotes (') after `ALTER USER` and keep quote (') after `mysql_native_password BY`

It is working for me also.

Comment: That was the only solution worked for me on localhost server using WAMP server :)

Comment: This seemed to fix it on my Mac's homebrew LAMP setup. Didn't experience this problem on debian though.

Comment: For those purely beginner, 1) `cd /usr/local/mysql/bin` 2) `./mysql -u root -p` 3) enter the line of code in this post

Answer (score 33):

Like many many people, I have had the same problem. Although the user is set to use mysql_native_password, and I can connect from the command line, the only way I could get mysqli() to connect is to add

> default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password

to the [mysqld] section of, in my setup on ubuntu 19.10, /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf

Comment: Also, keep in mind if the user is created prior this change it will not work. So, you should FIRST set default-authentication in the config and than create the user in order to work!

Comment: This worked on Ubuntu 20.04 with MySQL 8.0 and PHP 5.6. Note that you must set the tables to INNODB for this too work

Comment: after adding this to config I get the same error

Comment: This worked for me with Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (I had to edit `/etc/mysql/mysql.cnf` and run `systemctl restart mysql.service`), MySQL version 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.20.04.4, PHP 5.6, and I did not need to recreate the user.

Comment: You saved my hours... After changing the user's settings for MySQL native password, on Ubuntu 20.04 I had to add this line to `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`, and it worked like a charm. Thanks

Answer (score 32):

If you're on Windows and it's not possible to use `caching_sha2_password` at all, you can do the following:

1. rerun the MySQL Installer
2. select "Reconfigure" next to MySQL Server (the top item)
3. click "Next" until you get to "Authentication Method"
4. change "Use Strong Password Encryption for Authentication (RECOMMENDED)" to "Use Legacy Authentication Method (Retain MySQL 5.X Compatibility)
5. click "Next"
6. enter your Root Account Password in Accounts and Roles, and click "Check"
7. click "Next"
8. keep clicking "Next" until you get to "Apply Configuration"
9. click "Execute"

The Installer will make all the configuration changes needed for you.

Comment: man after a year of upvoting this answer my db was hacked...

Comment: I doubt this was the root cause of your database hack. 

Thanks for the post OP, it helped me configure MySQL for a legacy application running PHP 5.6.

Answer (score 21):

It's working for me (PHP 5.6 + PDO / MySQL Server 8.0 / Windows 7 64bits)

Edit the file `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini`:

```
default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password
```

Reset MySQL service on Windows, and in the MySQL Shell...

```
ALTER USER my_user@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

Comment: it works, thank you... we must config that 2 things: mysql conf and alter user

Answer (score 9):

I ran the following command
`ALTER USER 'root' @ 'localhost' identified with mysql_native_password BY 'root123';` in the command line and finally restart MySQL in local services.

Comment: no spaces here `'root' @ 'localhost'` should be read instead `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' identified with mysql_native_password BY 'root123';`

Answer (score 7):

If you're on a Mac, here's how to fix it. This is after tons of trial and error. Hope this helps others..

Debugging:

```
$mysql --verbose --help | grep my.cnf

$ which mysql
/usr/local/bin/mysql
```

Resolution:
nano /usr/local/etc/my.cnf

Add: default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password

```
-------
# Default Homebrew MySQL server config
[mysqld]
# Only allow connections from localhost
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
------
```

Finally Run: brew services restart mysql

Comment: Needed this... Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Now you can upgrade to PHP7.4 and MySQL will go with `caching_sha2_password` by default, so default MySQL installation will work with `mysqli_connect` No configuration required.

Comment: Not quite. It's buggy in 7.4.0 and 7.4.1. [Fixed in 7.4.2](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=78981)

Answer (score 4):

I tried this in Ubuntu 18.04
and is the only solution that worked for me:

```
ALTER USER my_user@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

Comment: perfect. I'm testing. The other answers require rehauling my entire system, which is currently working just to access one item. I'm think I need a rotating "HOT" (Always updated) server going forward.

Answer (score 1):

If you have not yet already changed your MySQL default authentication plugin, you can do so by:

1. Log in as `root` to MySQL
2. Run the following SQL command:

a. if you are running MySQL in a different server:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password
BY 'password';
```

b. if you are running MySQL in a different server:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password
BY 'password';
```

Answer (score 1):

**I have the similar issue. Before solving it lets first understand the problem.**

**MySQL 5.7 and earlier:**
These versions use `mysql_native_password` as the default authentication plugin. This plugin uses a simple password hashing algorithm and is widely supported by various MySQL client libraries, including older PHP versions.

**MySQL 8.x:** The default authentication plugin is `caching_sha2_password`, which provides better security through the SHA-256 hashing algorithm. This newer authentication method was not initially supported by all MySQL client libraries, including older versions of PHP's MySQL extensions (like mysqli and PDO).

**PHP 7.2 and earlier:**
These versions were released before or around the time MySQL 8.0 was released. As such, the default MySQL extensions in these PHP versions may not support `caching_sha2_password` out of the box.

**PHP 7.4 and later:** These versions have improved support for MySQL 8.x and its default `caching_sha2_password` authentication plugin. Thus, they can connect to MySQL 8.x databases using the new authentication method without requiring configuration changes.

So the problem is when you are using latest MySQL (v8.+) with old PHP ( 7.3.x and earlier) that does not have support for `caching_sha2_password` you might get similar issue.

to solve this issue you need change mysql default authentication plugin  from `caching_sha2_password` to `mysql_native_password`

**Update my.cnf then restart Mysql**

```
[mysqld]
default_authentication_plugin= mysql_native_password
```

**Login into mysql as root using terminal then run these**

*- when your mysql host is 'localhost'*

```
ALTER USER 'dbuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'root@123';
```

*- when your mysql host is other than 'localhost', like 10.10.0.2 etc.*

```
ALTER USER 'dbuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'root@123';
```

*[Note] make sure you replace `dbuser` with your actual database username.*

*- finally flush all privilege*

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using laravel 5.8 and having MAMP server got this error resolved by adding DB_SOCKET=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock in .env file like below

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=8889
DB_DATABASE=dbname
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
DB_SOCKET=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case when I was using WAMP server I fixed it using following

1. Note the port in  mySQL's "my.ini" file. In my case it was changed to **3308** when I was switching b/w MariaDB and MySQL DB.

[image]

2. Use the port number when you create mysqli object.

[image]

Using the above steps I was able to run the program successfully.

Answer (score 0):

#### phpMyAdmin GUI way

**Note:** This method may not work if you have the problem with root user account.

1. Login to phpMyAdmin as root.
2. Switch to "User Accounts" tab.
3. Select the username you get error with.
4. From the top buttons, switch to "Login Information" section.
5. In "Login Information" box, change "Authentication plugin" from "Caching sha2 authentication" to "Native MySQL authentication". Also, you must fill in other required fields, obviously, including username and password.
6. Save it by clicking on the "Go" button at the bottom.
7. Return back to terminal and enjoy. :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i'm using PHP `Symfony` framework and it's a silly mistake.

The database credential was wrong in `paramers.yml`.

After changing the credentials accordingly the problem was gone.

Answer (score 0):

In Digital Ocean Managed Mysql, we have an option to change encryption, you can change to legacy and it'll work ok.

Answer (score 0):

In my case:

I'm using `PHP 5.6` and `MYSQL 8`. Since `MYSQL 8` comes with `caching_sha2_password` as default authentication and `PHP 5.6` doesn't support it yet, i have to set MYSQL 8 authentication to `mysql_native_password` by doing:

add

```
default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
```

to the end of line of `/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf` configuration file in ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score -4):

I think it is not useful to configure the mysql server without caching_sha2_password encryption, we have to find a way to publish, send or obtain secure information through the network. As you see in the code below I dont use variable $db_name, and Im using a user in mysql server with standar configuration password. 
Just create a Standar user password and config all privilages. it works, but how i said without segurity.

```
<?php
$db_name="db";
$mysql_username="root";
$mysql_password="****";
$server_name="localhost";
$conn=mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_username,$mysql_password);

if ($conn) {
    echo "connetion success";
}
else{
    echo mysqli_error($conn);
}

?>
```