# PHP - problems connecting to a server

Tags: php, mysql, workbench

I have problems connecting to a server. Originally I was using UserSpice and had problems connecting so I decided to make a test with connecting manually with php but still got error(I am using MySQL Workbench) :

> PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password] in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\index.php on line 8
>
> PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2054): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\index.php on line 8

Here is my code:

```
<?php
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "test";
  $password = "";
  $DBname = "testing";

 $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $DBname);
```

I am pretty useless when it comes to PHP as what I am doing is graphic and web design so if you can help I will be really grateful!!

Thank you!

Comment: which version of PHP are you using?

Comment: you can find your answer in :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50027581/6636584

Comment: maybe the version of mysql is not compatible? here they make a downgrade of the version and work: https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/1390

Comment: are you sing a password? if no, passing null for the password is worth a try

Answer (score -1):

Hi there kindly check your default username which is root, let me share the code

```
    <?php
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "";
  $DBname = "testing";

 $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $DBname);
```

If it's work great, if not let me know.