# PHP - The server requested authentication method unknown to the client

Tags: mysql, php, iis

I want to connect to a MySQL database from PHP but I can't because "authentication method unknown", I found many solution but all of them about creating a new user with the old password type, but according to the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php), it should support the new password type. So is it possible to use the new MySQL password type with PHP 7.2.7?

### Versions

**PHP:** `7.2.7`
**MySQL Server:** `8.0.12`

### PHP Code

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
$conn->set_charset("utf8");
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
```

### Result

`Connection failed: The server requested authentication method unknown to the client`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php mysqli\_connect: authentication method unknown to the client \[caching\_sha2\_password\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50026939/php-mysqli-connect-authentication-method-unknown-to-the-client-caching-sha2-pa)

Comment: @MichaelHampton I also found this, but as I mentioned PHP 7.2.7 should support the caching_sha2_password, and I think there is a better solution than using the old password type. This is why I posted this question.

Comment: can you [SHOW CREATE USER user](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-create-user.html) and show the `php_info` for mysqli.