# Can not connect php 7.2 to mysql 8.0 The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]

Tags: php, mysql

I want to connect `mysql 8` to `php 7.2`, but always get error:

> The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]

I have altered the user to use the `mysql_native_password` plugin. But still can not connect.

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost'
  IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password
             BY 'root';
```

Do you have the solution?

Thanks,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [php mysqli\_connect: authentication method unknown to the client \[caching\_sha2\_password\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50026939/php-mysqli-connect-authentication-method-unknown-to-the-client-caching-sha2-pa)

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this is by re-initializing the database and switch to 'Use Legacy Password Encryption'.

MacOS X:

1. Click the Apple icon > System preferences > MySQL
2. Stop MySQL Server
3. Initialize Database
4. Use Legacy Password Encryption > Save
5. Start MySQL Server

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: In step 4 above, where do you see the option to "Use Legacy Password Encryption > Save?"

Comment: Edited my original answer and added a screenshot. Let me know if that helped.

Comment: Yes, that helps.  However, it doesn't look like mine.  My MySQL System Preference does not offer that option.  Where did you get mysql from?  I downloaded MySQL 8.0.19 from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/

Comment: I figured out why I don't have that option in my MySQL System Preference.  When you do "Initialize Database" it will read the /etc/my.cnf file first and if the directive to use the old authentication plugin already exists ( default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password ), you will not be presented with the option to choose.