# How to resolve ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation ALTER USER failed for 'root'@'localhost'?

Tags: mysql

I can't login with root ,I think root's password may be changed.But I can't change root's password either.

Mysql version is v8.0.16.

I have used `--init-file` to specificd alter sql at mysqld booting

```
alter user 'root'@'localhost' identified by 'mynewpassword'
```

but it doesn't work.

I used `--skip-grant-tables --user=mysql` so I could add a new user, and my new user works. I try to alter root,but it failed again.

```sql
mysql> alter user 'root'@'localhost' identified by 'mynewpassword';
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation ALTER USER failed for 'root'@'localhost'
```

here is the table user's content

```sql
mysql> select user,host from user;
+------------------+-----------+
| user             | host      |
+------------------+-----------+
| admin            | %         |
| mysql.infoschema | localhost |
| mysql.session    | localhost |
| mysql.sys        | localhost |
| root             | localhost |
+------------------+-----------+
```

Do anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 50):

You Can try:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '123';
```

rather than

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '123';
```

When you use the following command

```
mysql> use mysql;
mysql> select user,host from user;
```

you can find that root's host is '%'

```
mysql> select user, host from user;
+------------------+-----------+
| user             | host      |
+------------------+-----------+
| root             | %         |
| mysql.infoschema | localhost |
| mysql.session    | localhost |
| mysql.sys        | localhost |
+------------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Worked for me. I also did FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Answer (score 7):

According to [the mysql docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-user.html) and [this one](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html) - check the special `--init-file` option.
And then try to `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

Also, please see this related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555328/error-1396-hy000-operation-create-user-failed-for-jacklocalhost).

This should help.

Comment: Thank you very much , What I have tried is according [mysql docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html) but I do didn't flush after mysqld start. I think it should be as the same as skip-grant.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem but the error was only because of mysql syntax requiring to escape uderline character `_` in username using a backslash.

```
alter user 'user_db1'@'localhost' identified by 'mynewpassword'; ==>> caused error
alter user 'user\_db1'@'localhost' identified by 'mynewpassword'; ==>> success!
```

Answer (score 1):

@HuSharp suggested comment:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '123';
```

along with following this:
https://linuxhint.com/mysql-access-denied-user-root-localhost/
worked for me,
make sure to follow the proper password level

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'validate_password%';
```

Answer (score 1):

ALTER USER 'root'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '123';

Comment: This just copies part of the top-rated answer without any context or formatting. Please don't repeat answers.

Comment: No, it didn't work when I typed localhost. It was installed on 127.0.0.1 in the SQL table. When I did that, it worked.

Comment: Really, change localhost to IP works, +1

Comment: Please add this context to answer

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '123';
```

Replace `123` by your password, this worked for me.