# How can i delete this from mysql?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Tried some commands with drop user but it dont work see picture.

[image]

Comment: Which user you are logged on? Add code as text not as image

Comment: normaly with root

Comment: It looks like a problem of user rights : see post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56946299/how-to-resolve-error-1396-hy000-operation-alter-user-failed-for-rootlocal

Comment: Did you try to even google this before asking it here? Secondly, you are meant to type your questions rather than pasting screenshots.

Comment: yes, i did but nothing found for it

Comment: https://sebhastian.com/mysql-error-1396/#:~:text=The%20MySQL%20ERROR%201396%20occurs,from%20your%20MySQL%20database%20server.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Revoke all Privileges first before to proceed to drop user

`REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES, GRANT OPTION FROM 'bloguser'@'localhost';`

`DROP USER 'bloguser'@'localhost';`

This was lifted from https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-delete-remove-user-account-in-mysql-mariadb/

Always ensure you do a proper research before you come here to ask your questions

Comment: It gives me this "ERROR 1269 (HY000): Can't revoke all privileges for one or more of the requested users"

Comment: you should be doing this as a root user with all privileges granted. use the command ```SHOW GRANTS``` to see your privileges

Comment: i used this for login to sql 
`sudo mysql -u root`

Comment: and i have all privileges on root

Comment: what version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.32-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

Comment: ok i found a solution for it. I used phpmyadmin and deleted it and worked. Thx btw for the help.

Comment: Ok. I think what you should have done was first revoke all privileges then revoke grant option before dropping the user in that order.