# phpMyAdmin works normally but show me many errors

Tags: phpmyadmin

Hi every Body phpMyAdmin works fine and normally ,but i have those errors and i want to resolve it but it didn't .
I had try so many solutions but no result , please any one have a solution ?

Here is the capture :
[image]

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52364415/php-with-mysql-8-0-error-the-server-requested-authentication-method-unknown-to or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50026939/php-mysqli-connect-authentication-method-unknown-to-the-client-caching-sha2-pa

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL database has changed the way authentication occurs when a client connects. The old method still works, but the new one (called caching_sha2_password) is now the default. This release doesn't seem to have been coordinated well with PHP because PHP versions older than 7.4 don't have support for that new method.

What seems to have happened here is that your actual user seems to be configured to use the old method, mysql_native_password. There's a second user, the controluser, which is used by phpMyAdmin to enable some advanced features such as bookmarks, query history, and more. You could:

1. Upgrade your PHP installation to version 7.4 or newer so that the new authentication method works,
2. Change your controluser to use the old authentication method (from within phpMyAdmin, go to the User accounts tab, then "Edit privileges" for the pma user. Use the "Login information" tab and halfway down change the dropdown for "Authentication plugin" to "Native MySQL authentication" and finally click Go to save the changes)
3. Disable the controluser. If you don't use any of the advanced features, you can edit your configuration file `config.inc.php` and remove the two lines that reference 'controluser' and 'controlpass'. You may also have to remove the line defining 'pmadb', I don't recall off hand.