# Laravel PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i'm doing an Angular - Laravel application. When i use `php artisan migrate` i get these warnings

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'interbase' (tried: ext\interbase (The specified module could not be found.), ext\php_interbase.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8_12c' (tried: ext\oci8_12c (The specified module could not be found.), ext\php_oci8_12c.dll (The specified
module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_firebird' (tried: ext\pdo_firebird (The specified module could not be found.), ext\php_pdo_firebird.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_oci' (tried: ext\pdo_oci (The specified module could not be found.), ext\php_pdo_oci.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
```

I have uncommented the extensions in php.ini file and i still get these.

I also get a few more errors, but i think that they're connected to these warnings

```
  Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = daw and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  PDOException::("PDO::__construct(): The server requested authentication method
  unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]")
```

For database i use MySQL Server & Workbench

Comment: Are you actually using all those PHP Extensions? If you are using MySQL you dont actually need any of those that are reporting errors

Comment: Can you try changing the password encryption https://stackoverflow.com/a/50027581/10309425