# Laravel Sail Database Connection Refused Error

Tags: php, laravel, docker

I have created a new Laravel project in Laravel 8. I have set up Sail installation correctly, everything working fine for the database connection locally but when I try to connect my database using Sail it gives me an error

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = laravel8 and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

I have already cleared my config and cache files.

Answer (score 106):

I was researching the same problem and found this.

https://github.com/laravel/sail/blob/7457004969dd62fa727fbc596bb2accccb1409a5/src/SailServiceProvider.php#L31

The code shows an artisan command added by laravel sail - `sail:install` which overwrites your .env file host variables with service names.

**I changed `DB_HOST` from `127.0.0.1` to `mysql` and it was fixed**

*Edit to answer questions:*

*Sail is based on Docker, to establish a connection between two Docker containers on the same Docker network, you can reference the container by its name, and Docker will handle the resolution for you.
This is why we use `mysql` instead of the address*

Comment: Hello, I am facing the same issue. DB_HOST is already mysql. I can log in to the DB and see it's empty. When I try to run "sail artisan migrate" I get the same error message. Any idea what it could be?

Comment: This works, but I'm very curious to know the significance of "mysql" - is it a special keyword used by Laravel when accessing dbhost, or is based on the docker image name of mysql.. EDIT: Actually, it might be invoking mysql directly from the command line?

Comment: Good answer, that was exactly my case.

Comment: how do i have to write that command? because $ sail:install didnt work

Comment: Great that worked. I had to `sail down -v` do remove the stored mysql volume with the wrong config and `sail up -d` to rebuild. After that it worked.

Comment: This did it for me. Thank you!!!!! I was about to give up all hope.

Comment: @AlexanderTaubenkorb This was the only solution given here that worked for me.

Comment: I am using mariadb so i needed to add `DB_HOST=mariadb` in my .env file and `container_name: mariadb` in the docker-compose.yml .

Comment: This is interesting. In my case, GET methods are working fine, but in POST I encountered the same error. The change in DB_HOST also fixed mine. Is this a bug ?

Comment: I was stuck in this issue for hours with multiple re-installations! 
Thanks for your suggestion. finally, the issue was solved.

Answer (score 27):

On cmd just run this command

```
docker network inspect bridge
```

You will get response like (similar) this:

```
[
{
    "Name": "bridge",
    "Id": "695c284c7b184839edf97d48161922dfe6c4827d0db917c3278f5634af7e00e2",
    "Created": "2022-02-22T22:17:30.8583513Z",
    "Scope": "local",
    "Driver": "bridge",
    "EnableIPv6": false,
    "IPAM": {
        "Driver": "default",
        "Options": null,
        "Config": [
            {
                "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
            }
        ]
    },
    .....
}
```

]

Copy "`Gateway`" ip address and replace with `DB_HOST` value in `.env` file. It will work

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting another error, but seems to be because of my PHP version (https://stackoverflow.com/a/50027581/7242535)

Comment: Thanks a lot @softiso! Also could we know why the `mysql` value stops working?

Comment: Thank you very much. But my question now is why it worked and if it wouldn't work if we had gotten the ip of the database container

Answer (score 17):

if you want run mysql in different port for example 3307 like below

```
ports:
  - 3307:3306
```

you should add FORWARD_DB_PORT environment variable to .env file like this

```
DB_PORT=3306 // this is for container port
FORWARD_DB_PORT=3307 // this is for local port
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed as I have moved the docker mysql port. Thanks

Comment: I just needed to add the FORWARD_DB_PORT. It works for me. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Changing DB_USERNAME from **sail** to **root** worked for me. I guess sail did not have the required privileges.

```
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=database
DB_USERNAME=root # changed from sail
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue after creating a second sail project in my docker. It wasn't (still isn't) accepting the sail username or password but I could go in with root which gave me the error you gave above. I went to the Desktop Docker app, clicked the running container, found the mysql portion and ran the CLI, typed `mysql` and then ran the query `CREATE DATABASE yourdatabasename;` migration ran perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should match the environment variables of .env.testing, since, as willpercey-gb says, the `sail:install` command updates the environment variables of .env, but not of .env.testing.

Answer (score -2):

First off
stop all services using brew especially MySQL

```
brew services stop MySQL
```

in your docker-yaml file:

```
laravel.test
   ports:
     - '70:80'
mysql:
   ports:
     - '3456:3306'
```

Now run your sail artisan migrate command.

this should solve your problem.

Comment: You don't need to stop the mysql service if you have changed the host port. In your case, the host port is, 3456