# Why won't Laravel Sail allow me to connect to the DB

Tags: php, laravel, docker, debugging, laravel-sail

Anyone familiar with using Laravel Sail?  I can't find for the life of me figure out why I can't connect to `myDb` using the credentials provided when installing Sail.

My DB credentials in the `.env` file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3307
DB_DATABASE=myDb
DB_USERNAME=sail
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

I've tried:

- switching `DB_HOST` back and forth from `127.0.0.1` to `localhost`
  but still getting that same error.
- switching `DB_HOST` to mysql but still getting that same error.
- running `docker ps -a | grep mysql` and the output is: `8b1ef6c28b4e   mysql/mysql-server:8.0   "/entrypoint.sh mysq…"   4 minutes ago   Up 4 minutes (healthy)   3306/tcp, 33060-33061/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3307->3307/tcp      myApp-mysql-1` so no issues with the connection per the output.
- running `./vendor/bin/sail sail mysql -u root -p` and it allowed me access to mysql on the CLI
- almost everything else out there to no avail

Not sure what else to do.  How can I connect to my db in a GUI?

`docker-compose.yml` file:

```
# For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.1
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.1/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
            - '${HMR_PORT:-8080}:8080'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3307}:3307'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
        volumes:
            - 'sail-mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
            - './vendor/laravel/sail/database/mysql/create-testing-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-create-testing-database.sh'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p${DB_PASSWORD}"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sail-mysql:
        driver: local
```

Comment: Did you delete the docker image and recreate it after the changes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Sail Database Connection Refused Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65576513/laravel-sail-database-connection-refused-error)

Answer (score 1):

Change the `DB_HOST` variable to `mysql` as the following:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3307
DB_DATABASE=myDb
DB_USERNAME=sail
DB_PASSWORD=password
```